# List mount points owner and group

Tags: filesystems, mount, hp-ux

I'm running HPUX 11.x and I was wondering if there's a command that would list all the mount point owner and group. I want a listing like `df` or `bdf` but with ownership information.

Comment: Are you looking for the mount points, as in the root of each mounted filesystem, or for the mount points, as in the directories that are hidden behind mounted filesystems?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a `for` iteration using the content of [/etc/mnttab](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man4/mnttab.4.html).